# delete an object in a nested array which has key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, lodash

i want to delete the only low-level object(for example in below code, under personal data there are two objects... i want to delete one object where action: old) under each section, where "action": "OLD"

I'm using lodash in my project

```
[
  {
    "clientDetails": {
      "personalData": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    },
    "clientAddress": {
      "primaryAddress": [
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ],
      "secondaryAddress": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "clientDemise": {
      "deathDetails": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    },
    "clientMarital": {
      "divorceInformation": [
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ],
      "marraigeInformation": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

sorry for the wrong presentation, this is the first time I'm posting a question

Comment: What should be the o/p for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just few lines can achieve this considering

```
input = your input
```

This peace of code will do the work

```
for (var i of input) {
  for (var j in i) {
   var ob = i[j];
   for (var k in ob) {
     var index = _.findIndex(ob[k], {'action': 'OLD'});
     if (index > -1) {
       ob[k].splice(index, 1);
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice, short solution. You can remove the `toRemove` variable, btw. Also, you could turn this into a code snippet, and just include lodash as an external library.

Comment: Thank u so much for the suggestion, I removed the unnecessary variable, Will create code snippet if needed.

Comment: But this can't be used to remove multiple entry of unwanted data (in case required)

Comment: your code works ... thanks.. but it throws error ob[k].splice is not a function  for example in above code if there is no primary address @ShyamTayal

Comment: I am considering last level fields to be an array, If not so add a type check in the third loop to avoid any error. Hope it helps

Comment: @ShyamTayal thanks it worked, i have one more problem with this it is also deleting object which has no action

Comment: Add a check 
`if (index > -1)` to fix it , Fixed in solution too

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript filters. Reduce your bundle size by not using lodash.

```
// it's upto you, you can use new Array() as well and insert if(ktm.action==='NEW')
clients = clients.filter(function(itm) {
  Object.keys(itm).forEach(function(Okey, Ovalue) {
    Object.keys(itm[Okey]).forEach(function(inkey, invalue) {
      itm[Okey][inkey].filter(function(ktm) {
        if (ktm.action === 'OLD') {
          // perform your logic, either you can insert into new Array() or 
          // delete that object and return clients
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via something like this without lodash:

```js
var data = [{ "clientDetails": { "personalData": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] }, "clientAddress": { "primaryAddress": [{ "action": "OLD", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "NEW", "id": "12445" } ], "secondaryAddress": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] } }, { "clientDemise": { "deathDetails": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] }, "clientMarital": { "divorceInformation": [{ "action": "OLD", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "NEW", "id": "12445" } ], "marraigeInformation": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] } } ]

const removeOld = (data) => data.map(x => 
   Object.entries(x).reduce((r, [k,v]) => {
      r[k] = Object.entries(v).map(([o,p]) => 
        ({[o]: p.filter(n => n.action != 'OLD')}))
      return r
   },{}))

console.log(removeOld(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Another way would be to utilize recursion similar to @Vanojx1 approach but in ES6:

```js
var data = [{ "clientDetails": { "personalData": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] }, "clientAddress": { "primaryAddress": [{ "action": "OLD", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "NEW", "id": "12445" } ], "secondaryAddress": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] } }, { "clientDemise": { "deathDetails": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] }, "clientMarital": { "divorceInformation": [{ "action": "OLD", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "NEW", "id": "12445" } ], "marraigeInformation": [{ "action": "NEW", "id": "12345" }, { "action": "OLD", "id": "12445" } ] } } ]

const removeOld = (data) => 
  Array.isArray(data) ? data.filter(x => x.action != 'OLD').map(x => removeOld(x)) :
  typeof(data) == 'object' ? Object.entries(data).reduce((r, [k,v]) => (r[k] = removeOld(v), r), {}) : 
  data

console.log(removeOld(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's not mutate the original input data, clone it with a customizer, and reject the unwanted stuffs (if they exists) inside the customizer to have cleaner cloned output as expected. You can use [lodash#cloneDeepWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeepWith)

```
_.cloneDeepWith(input, v => _.find(v, {action: "OLD"}) ? _.reject(v, {action: "OLD"}) : undefined);
```

This is just an example of having (hard coded) of what you want to reject. but you can wrap this in a call back and take the reject criteria as an argument to make it dynamic.

So here we go:

```js
let input = [{"clientDetails":{"personalData":[{"action":"NEW","id":"12345"},{"action":"OLD","id":"12445"}]},"clientAddress":{"primaryAddress":[{"action":"OLD","id":"12345"},{"action":"NEW","id":"12445"}],"secondaryAddress":[{"action":"NEW","id":"12345"},{"action":"OLD","id":"12445"}]}},{"clientDemise":{"deathDetails":[{"action":"NEW","id":"12345"},{"action":"OLD","id":"12445"}]},"clientMarital":{"divorceInformation":[{"action":"OLD","id":"12345"},{"action":"NEW","id":"12445"}],"marraigeInformation":[{"action":"NEW","id":"12345"},{"action":"OLD","id":"12445"}]}}],
    clear = (input, rej) => (
      _.cloneDeepWith(input, v => _.find(v, rej) ? _.reject(v, rej) : undefined)
    ),
    res;
  
res = clear(input, {action: "OLD"}); //you can filter out action: OLD
console.log(res);

res = clear(input, {action: "NEW"}); //you can filter out action: NEW
console.log(res);

res = clear(input, d => d.action==="OLD"); //you can filter with custom callback with complex logic
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tks amazing lodash - you saved my bacon

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your data is going to be fairly consistent (i.e. similar to what you've included in your question), you could do something like this:

```js
const mapObj = (f, obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = f(obj[key], key)
        return acc
    }, {})
}

const filterData = data => {
    // the data itself is an array, so iterate over each item in the array
    return data.map(x1 => {
        // x1 is an object, so need to iterate over each item in the object
        return mapObj(x2 => {
            // x2 is an object, so need to iterate over each item in the object
            return mapObj(x3 => {
                // x3 is an array of objects. each item in the array has an action key which could equal "NEW" or "OLD". get rido of the items with action === "OLD"
                return x3.filter(x4 => x4.action !== "OLD")
            }, x2)
        }, x1)
    })
}

const data = [
  {
    "clientDetails": {
      "personalData": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    },
    "clientAddress": {
      "primaryAddress": [
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ],
      "secondaryAddress": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "clientDemise": {
      "deathDetails": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    },
    "clientMarital": {
      "divorceInformation": [
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ],
      "marraigeInformation": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

const result = filterData(data)
console.log(result)
```

If you want a more generic solution that can take data of any structure and just removes all objects with an action equal to 'OLD':

```js
const reduceObj = (f, initial, obj) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        return f(acc, obj[key], key)
    }, initial)
}

const isObject = x => x !== null && typeof x === 'object'

const removeAllOld = data => {
    if(Array.isArray(data)) {
        return data.reduce((acc, value) => {
            // don't include the item if it has a key named 'action' that is equal to 'OLD'
            if(value.action && value.action === 'OLD') return acc

            acc.push(removeAllOld(value))
            return acc
        }, [])
    }
    else if(isObject(data)) {
        return reduceObj((acc, value, key) => {
            // don't include the item if it has a key named 'action' that is equal to 'OLD'
            if(value.action && value.action === 'OLD') return acc

            acc[key] = removeAllOld(value)
            return acc
        }, {}, data)
    }
    else {
        return data
    }
}

const data = [
  {
    "clientDetails": {
      "personalData": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    },
    "clientAddress": {
      "primaryAddress": [
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ],
      "secondaryAddress": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "clientDemise": {
      "deathDetails": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    },
    "clientMarital": {
      "divorceInformation": [
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ],
      "marraigeInformation": [
        {
          "action": "NEW",
          "id": "12345"
        },
        {
          "action": "OLD",
          "id": "12445"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

console.log(removeAllOld(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a deep copy like this:

```
    const array = [
      {
        "clientDetails": {
          "personalData": [
            {
              "action": "NEW",
              "id": "12345"
            },
            {
              "action": "OLD",
              "id": "12445"
            }
          ]
        },
        "clientAddress": {
          "primaryAddress": [
            {
              "action": "OLD",
              "id": "12345"
            },
            {
              "action": "NEW",
              "id": "12445"
            }
          ],
          "secondaryAddress": [
            {
              "action": "NEW",
              "id": "12345"
            },
            {
              "action": "OLD",
              "id": "12445"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "clientDemise": {
          "deathDetails": [
            {
              "action": "NEW",
              "id": "12345"
            },
            {
              "action": "OLD",
              "id": "12445"
            }
          ]
        },
        "clientMarital": {
          "divorceInformation": [
            {
              "action": "OLD",
              "id": "12345"
            },
            {
              "action": "NEW",
              "id": "12445"
            }
          ],
          "marraigeInformation": [
            {
              "action": "NEW",
              "id": "12345"
            },
            {
              "action": "OLD",
              "id": "12445"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]    
    function removeOldAction(a) {
    if (a instanceof Array) {
        let copiee = [];
        for (let item in a) {
            const propValue = removeOldAction(a[item]);
            if(propValue) {
                copiee.push(propValue);
            }
        }
        return copiee;
    }
    if (a instanceof Object) {
        if (a['action'] === 'OLD') { 
            return; 
        }
        let copiee = {};
        for (let key in a) {
            copiee[key] = removeOldAction(a[key]);
        }
        return copiee;
    } 
    return a;
}

    console.log(removeOldAction(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Structure independent solution checking for action in each object node

```js
var data=[{clientDetails:{personalData:[{action:"NEW",id:"12345"},{action:"OLD",id:"12445"}]},clientAddress:{primaryAddress:[{action:"OLD",id:"12345"},{action:"NEW",id:"12445"}],secondaryAddress:[{action:"NEW",id:"12345"},{action:"OLD",id:"12445"}]}},{clientDemise:{deathDetails:[{action:"NEW",id:"12345"},{action:"OLD",id:"12445"}]},clientMarital:{divorceInformation:[{action:"OLD",id:"12345"},{action:"NEW",id:"12445"}],marraigeInformation:[{action:"NEW",id:"12345"},{action:"OLD",id:"12445"}]}}];

const reducer = (curr) => {
  if(_.isArray(curr))
    return _(curr)
      .filter(el => !('action' in el && el.action == 'OLD'))
      .map(el => reducer(el))
      .value()
  else if(_.isObject(curr)) {
    return _(curr)
      .mapValues(el => reducer(el))
      .value()
  } else
    return curr;
};

console.log(reducer(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```